# DPA 4061 as Lavalier? 

Tags: dpa, lavalier

Has anyone used them as a lavalier mic (dialogue, not singing)?

The reason I'm keen on these (yes I know they are expensive), is that I can get a matched pair to use as binaural mics and they are great to have in my kit for recording SFX. I like that I can put a high frequency boost grill for when the cloths are a little thick... So although these mics are pricey, I feel that they are versatile, and thus cheaper on the long run.

Also, are the 4061s definitely better than the 4060s as a lavalier? The 4061s run less hot than the 4060s.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3):

The term 'better' really depends on the particular use. As I understand it the 4061s are a less sensitive 4060 and are very good for recording loud sound sources (eg placing close to a vehicle exhaust) If you were recording quieter sounds or ambiences then the 4060 would be a better choice...

Comment: Thanks for the response. By better, I ment it in relation to dialogue recording (chest mounted lav). 

Answer (score 3):

The 4060s will clip if you're recording a loud source. I've taped mine to loud machinery or an acoustic guitar strummed loud and they'll clip on occasion. But they are fantastic sounding mics and work great for more delicate stuff. I'd go with them over the 4061s, unless you're planning on just recording loud spl stuff.

Comment: Thanks for that. My priority is to use it to record dialogue on location, so I think the 4060s would be a better choice, although I wish I could use them for louder sources too. Decisions decisions... 

Answer (score 3):

The 4060s are definitely more sensitive than the 4061 and handle a little less SPL.  That said, I used the DPA 4060s when recording my rocket library and they did pretty damn well.

Comment: That's great to know! The DPA guys seemed to recommend the 4061s even for dialogue, but he didn't seem fully confident about that advice, so I think the 4060s would be a better allround solution. 

Comment: andrew, what reasons did they give for the 4061s?

Answer (score 2):

The 4060 is the perfect lav in my opinion. The 4061 is good as well, though you'll have to gain it more, but it has a very low noise floor, so you'll be fine on most occasions. Normally I would use the 4060 for dialogue and switch to the 4061 for loud surroundings / shouting. Be sure to get a couple of the concealers to go with the mics, if you want to use them as lavs, it is a very good solution to the common problem of cloth noise.

Comment: Thanks Morten, that's the exact answer I was after. Definitally gonna get myself some concealers. Do you have that freq boost grill? Should I buy them as well?  

Answer (score 1):

The 4060 is in no way inferior to the 4061. Many highly regarded nature recordists use a stereo pair of 4060s for ambience with great results, the 4061s would not be as suitable for this use. The only time I would go for a 4061 would be in fairly or very loud conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I think considering my main application will be dialogue recording and the rest just a bonus, I'm better off getting the 4060s...

Answer (score 0):

DPA's 4060 and 4061 are THE lavaliers. Sometimes they record too much :-) Eg, when the source sounds bad it will be very truthful, so - bad :-) But otherwise, great quality. You get what you pay for. And you can easily use them with 48V adaptors for music recording  (google ONNO SCHOLTZE)

Comment: hehe, sounds good to me :-) 